# Image not displayed after resize

Tags: php, image, resize

I have the following php code, which has been snipped for brevity. I am having trouble with the code after $lastImg is declared, specifically size never seems to get assigned any value, and the hence outputwidth and outputheight remain blank. I have been unable to spot the cause of this.

pic_url is just a string in the database, and definitely points to a valid image. When I run my page without the code to resize, the image is displayed perfectly.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

if (isset($_GET["cmd"]))
    $cmd = $_GET["cmd"];
else
    die("You should have a 'cmd' parameter in your URL");

$pk = $_GET["pk"];
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "someuser", "notreal");

if(!$con)
{
    die('Connection failed because of' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8'); 
mysql_select_db("somedb",$con);

if($cmd == "GetAuctionData")
{
    $sql="SELECT * FROM AUCTIONS WHERE ARTICLE_NO ='$pk'";
    $sql2="SELECT ARTICLE_DESC FROM AUCTIONS WHERE ARTICLE_NO ='$pk'";
    $htmlset = mysql_query($sql2);
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($htmlset);

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $columns = array('FINISHED', 'WATCH', 'PRIVATE_AUCTION', 'REVISED', 'PAYPAL_ACCEPT', 'PRE_TERMINATED', 'PIC_XXL', 'PIC_DIASHOW');
        foreach($columns as $column)
        {
            $$column = $row[$column] ? 'YES' : 'NO';
        }

        $lastImg = $row['PIC_URL']; 
        $maxWidth  = 250;
        $maxHeight = 300;

            $size = getimagesize($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $lastImg);
var_dump($size);
echo "SIZE = ".$size."";
if ($size) {
    $imageWidth  = $size[0];
    $imageHeight = $size[1];
    $wRatio = $imageWidth / $maxWidth;
    $hRatio = $imageHeight / $maxHeight;
    $maxRatio = max($wRatio, $hRatio);
else {
die(print_r(error_get_last())); }
else if ($maxRatio > 1) {
        $outputWidth = $imageWidth / $maxRatio;
        $outputHeight = $imageHeight / $maxRatio;
    } else {
        $outputWidth = $imageWidth;
        $outputHeight = $imageHeight;
    }
}

        echo "<h1>".$row['ARTICLE_NAME']."</h1>
            <div id='rightlayer'>
            <img src='".$lastImg."' width='".$outputWidth."' height='".$outputHeight."'>
            </div>";
    }
}

mysql_free_result($result);
```

Comment: What data type is PIC_URL? What's the definition of getimagesize() and where are you getting it from?

Comment: @Kesser: http://php.net/getimagesize

Comment: You are aware of the SQL injection vulnerability, right? Or is this just a simplification?

Comment: It is a simplication, but I have not investigated making everything more secure completely yet. I am planning to switch everything to prepared statements.

Comment: The "die(print_r(error_get_last()));" should not be in the inner else, but you should create a new else for the "if ($size) {" part. That way, you can get the error, responsible for not assigning size

Comment: You're not doing yourself any favours having code formatted like that - I've re-indented it

Comment: Fixed, but results in a blank page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to get the right error message, change your code to:

```
$size = getimagesize($lastImg);
echo "SIZE = ".$size."";
if ($size) {
    $imageWidth  = $size[0];
    $imageHeight = $size[1];
    $wRatio = $imageWidth / $maxWidth;
    $hRatio = $imageHeight / $maxHeight;
    $maxRatio = max($wRatio, $hRatio);

    if ($maxRatio > 1) {
        $outputWidth = $imageWidth / $maxRatio;
        $outputHeight = $imageHeight / $maxRatio;
    } else {
        $outputWidth = $imageWidth;
        $outputHeight = $imageHeight;
    }
} else {
    die(print_r(error_get_last()));
}
```

After that, we can look at the error and try to investigate further.

Comment: this is the error I got:

SIZE = Array ( [type] => 2 [message] => getimagesize(http://i10.ebayimg.com/08/i/001/1d/10/8d15_1.JPG?set_id=800005007) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted [file] => /var/www/intern/ebay/get_auction.php [line] => 48 ) 1

Comment: URL file-access is not permitted with your server configuration. Do you have access to it?

Comment: See http://de3.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen for an explanation.

Comment: I do not really have access to the configuration. Why was it disabled..what were the security concerns? Would it make more sense to download the image locally and save it?

Comment: I don't know why this option was disabled. Downloading the image should be possible (and the only solution) via curl. fopen() will show the same behaviour as getimagesize()

Comment: So I would download the image with curl, and then change lastimg to point to where it was downloaded?

Comment: That seems like the only solution.

Comment: I have managed to get URL file access enabled. What is the best way to save the image to a file locally without using curl?

Comment: This "answer" does not provide a resolution, it merely assists in collecting Debugging details.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to say it looks like $row['PIC_URL'] might not point to a valid image, thats the only reason getimagesize would fail. What does your database structure in AUCTIONS look like?

Comment: pic_url is just a string, however it is definitely pointing to a valid image.

Comment: An "answer" should not need to ask for more details.  That's what comments under the question are for.

Answer (score 0):

1st. do a

```
print_r($row)
```

just below your

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

And see if the array PIC_URL is set there

2nd you really should do a safe Query.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM AUCTIONS WHERE ARTICLE_NO ='$pk'";
```

Should be

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM AUCTIONS WHERE ARTICLE_NO = %d", mysql_real_escape_string($pk));
```

Same with the other SQL query.

Comment: This "answer" does not provide a resolution, it merely assists in collecting Debugging details.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few things that conflict with each other:

```
$size = getimagesize($lastImg);

echo "<img src='".$lastImg."' ...>"
```

`getimagesize` expects a filename while `<img>` expects a URL.

You might try something like this:

```
$root = str_replace($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);

$size = getimagesize($root . $lastImg);
```

[**EDIT**] Sorry. `DOCUMENT_ROOT` wasn't right.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$lastImg = $row['PIC_URL'];
var_dump($row);
die();
```

to see if you have anything in $row['PIC_URL'].

Comment: This "answer" does not provide a resolution, it merely assists in collecting Debugging details.